# How can I get user creation code using DBMS_METADATA?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, privileges, dbms-metadata

I need to get a DDL script of a partucular user.

I'm trying to use the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('USER', user) to get a ddl of current user, but I get an error: "object "user1" of type USER not found in schema "user1.

I guess, this means that I don't have necessary privileges. What privilege is this that's needed? Or maybe there are some other problem?